# How to retrieve git Commit Id from a C# Application?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I am looking into a CI Build Automation Task and I want to name my builds using the Git Commit Id.
I am planning to write a C# program to do this. What Libraries I can use to call Git repositories from C#? I am able to call into local repository clone and retrieve this information using git.exe(Windows) or libgit2sharp but I don't know how to do it on a remote source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a CI perspective, you may be willing to build a specific branch.

The following piece of code demonstrates this.

```
using (Repository repo = Repository.Clone(url, localPath))
{
    // Retrieve the branch to build
    var branchToBuild = repo.Branches["vNext"];

    // Updates the content of the working directory with the content of the branch
    branchToBuild.Checkout();

    // Perform your build magic here ;-)
    Build();

    // Retrieve the commit sha of the branch that has just been built
    string sha = branchToBuild.Tip.Sha;

    // Package your build artifacts using the sha to name the package
    Package(sha);
}
```

**Note:** `url` can either point to:

- a remote http url (`http://www.example.com/repo.git`)
- a location on the CI server (`file:///C:/My%20Documents/repo.git`)
- a location on the network (`file://server/repos/repo.git`)

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) for quite some time, and it is good.

Below is a sample, which will iterate through the `commits` in your `url`.

*Note:* I had to do a `clone`, not sure if there is a better way:

```
string url = "http://github.com/libgit2/TestGitRepository";

using (Repository repo = Repository.Clone(url, @"C:\Users\Documents\test"))
{
    foreach (var commit in repo.Commits)
    {
        var commitId = commit.Id;
        var commitRawId = commitId.RawId;
        var commitSha = commitId.Sha; //0ab936416fa3bec6f1bf3d25001d18a00ee694b8
        var commitAuthorName = commit.Author.Name;

        commits.Add(commit);
    }
}
```